# Tips on organizing Active Directory for a global company with different departments

Tags: active-directory, groups, service-accounts, organizational-unit

I have started to read and implement some of the basic domain architecture implementation, one of the question I have is what is the latest trend in organizing the active directory OU's, Groups and Users.

I want to work on a test environment so that I could get a better for understanding of scaling and domain change (due to company acquisitions, company name change or anything).

How would we maintain expired accounts and service accounts?

Please suggest if there are any books, articles which I can read. I know these questions are generic and might be a duplicate but would love to read about latest trend in the AD organization.

Thanks for reading...

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft's MCITP Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Administrator](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735663270)

[Windows PowerShell(TM) 2.0 Administrator's Pocket Consultant](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735625956)